# How to access parent methods from submodule?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have the following module/class and submodule setup

`MyAPI.js`

```
class MyAPI {
  construction(){
    this.food = require('./Food');
  }
}
module.exports = MyAPI;
```

`Food.js`

```
class Food {
  constructor(){
    ...
  }
}
module.exports = Food;
```

`app.js`

```
var api = require('./MyAPI');
var taco = new api.food;
var cheeseburger = new api.food;
```

What I'm wondering, is it possible to call upon MyAPI properties and functions form within `Food.js`? Do I need to pass `this` into the require somehow?

```
this.food = require('./Food')(this); // this didn't work...
```

The above resulted in this:

```
TypeError: Class constructors cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

But why would I use `new` in the MyAPI constructor?

What is the best approach here to do subclasses and submodules and creating new objects from them?

Comment: You want `new (require('./Food'))(this)`. In any case, you should never put constructors as methods on instances.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing classes and instances:

```
var MyAPI = require('./MyAPI');//this is a class
var apiInstance = new MyAPI();//the creates a new instance of your class
var taco = new apiInstance.food //the food property on your api is a class not an instance
var tacoInstance = new taco();
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.food` is assigned in the constructor of `MyApi`, so you will need to instantiate `MyApi` to have the property accessible.

```
var Api = require('./MyAPI');
var apiInstance = new Api();
var foodInstance = new apiInstance.food();
```

From your comment, it seems like you want properties of MyApi, particularly `config` to be accessible by submodules. I don't see a way of doing this except to make your top level API object a singleton:

```
var MyAPI =  {
  config: { setting: 'default' },
  Food: require('./Food')
}

module.exports = MyAPI;
```

```
var MyApi = require('./my-api.js');

class Food {
  constructor(){
    // MyApi.config
  }
}
module.exports = Food;
```

Looking at the AWS [source](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/lib/aws.js#L52) they are doing something similar (except `config` is it's own module mounted on the top level `AWS` object).

Comment: So does that mean that I can only create one instance of apiInstance.food? It seems weird to use `new` in the api constructor like that instead of in my App.

Comment: In this case yes. It totally depends on how you are using this. You can just as easily expose the `Food` constructor as a static property on your class. You would typically want an instance to be able to hold the state for a connection (auth details etc).

Comment: How does AWS do it with their SDK here then http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-examples.html ? They create the AWS object and then instantiate the S3 class as a property of the AWS object using `new`? That approach is what I'm trying to emulate.